# Report Server pointing to another Reporting Server

Tags: authentication, ssrs

I am trying to configure a public facing Reporting Server, which is actually talking to a private Reporting Server backend.  I have established the connections between the two of them, but I cannot get access to the reports because it keeps asking me for a Windows User when I try to connect to the Public facing website.  Is there anyway that I can stop this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have the reporting server (MSSQL ) to windows authentication and for some reason you might have some ports closed . Please see the guide bellow for ports http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx used by MSSQL (in general ) and guide Reporting server security (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522728.aspx) .

Comment: I'll give this a go